# What happens to existing topic's partitions when a new broker is added to the Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say you have a one node Kakfa cluster and you create a topic with 2 partitions, because you want to be able to consume in parallel.

Then a new broker joins the cluster.

Will this trigger a redistribution of existing topic's partitions too, I mean, will all the data from the second partition of our topic be moved to the second broker ?

Or will the new broker be involved only in the future topic's partitions distribution ?

Comment: Note, this is one of the reasons why it is sensible to build a Kafka cluster with a seemingly nonsensical configuration, for example 3 brokers and 14 partitions per topic. While this seemingly doesn't make sense because you will not get 14x throughput/performance because you will be limited by some bottleneck somewhere due to having only 3 physical machines, it allows you to scale the cluster hardware in future. You can add additional brokers, and with a bit of manual work, move existing partitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kafka does not automatically redistribute existing partitions when brokers are added to a a cluster.

This is for a few reasons:

- Moving partitions can cause a lot of inter broker traffic and extra load on the cluster.
- It's hard to determine which partitions to move. In your case, it's trivial but imagine a cluster with 1000s of partitions and many brokers.

There is a section in the Kafka docs regarding [cluster expansion](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion).

There are a few tools to perform such an operation:

- `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` is the default Kafka tool that can be used to rebalance partitions across new brokers in a controlled way.
- https://github.com/DataDog/kafka-kit
- https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control