# Execute to alter kafka topic partition number, occurred UnknownServerException with other topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I execute shell script kafka-topics.sh to alter partition count from 3 to 10.

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper xxx.xx.xxx.xx:2181/my-broker-0 --alter --topic target-topic-example-1 --partitions 10
```

As soon as I execute the command, Kafka cluster occurred errors.

```
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,954] INFO Created log for partition [target-topic-example-1,5] in /data/kafka/brokers with properties {flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, segment.bytes -> 536870912, preallocate -> false, cleanup.policy ->    [delete], delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, segment.ms -> 604800000, min.insync.replicas -> 1, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, retention.ms -> 259200000, max.message.bytes -> 10000000, message.format.version -> 0.10.1-IV2, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, retention.bytes -> -1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, compression.type -> producer, unclean.leader.election.enable -> true, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, flush.ms ->          9223372036854775807}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,955] INFO Partition [target-topic-example-1,5] on broker 8: No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition [target-topic-example-1,5] (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,957] INFO Completed load of log target-topic-example-1-4 with 1 log segments and log end offset 0 in 1 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,957] INFO Created log for partition [target-topic-example-1,4] in /data/kafka/brokers with properties {flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, segment.bytes -> 536870912, preallocate -> false, cleanup.policy ->    [delete], delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, segment.ms -> 604800000, min.insync.replicas -> 1, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, retention.ms -> 259200000, max.message.bytes -> 10000000, message.format.version -> 0.10.1-IV2, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, retention.bytes -> -1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, compression.type -> producer, unclean.leader.election.enable -> true, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, flush.ms ->          9223372036854775807}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,958] INFO Partition [target-topic-example-1,4] on broker 8: No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition [target-topic-example-1,4] (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,958] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 8] Removed fetcher for partitions target-topic-example-1-5,target-topic-example-1-4 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,958] INFO Truncating log target-topic-example-1-5 to offset 0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,958] INFO Truncating log target-topic-example-1-4 to offset 0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-11-20 14:45:29,961] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 8] Added fetcher for partitions List([target-topic-example-1-5, initOffset 0 to broker BrokerEndPoint(1,My-broker02-172.cm.skp,9092)] , [target-topic-example-1-4, initOffset 0 to broker BrokerEndPoint(0,My-  broker01-172.cm.skp,9092)] ) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)

[2018-11-20 14:45:30,062] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [other-topic-1,3] to broker 1:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2018-11-20 14:45:30,070] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [other-topic-2,0] to broker 1:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2018-11-20 14:45:30,070] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [other-topic-3,3] to broker 1:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2018-11-20 14:45:30,070] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [other-topic-4,0] to broker 1:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

My command to change the number of partitions worked well as a result.
However, I do not know what the above errors are like.

(For reference, there are a total of 10 brokers, and more than 500 topics.)

Comment: Sounds like broker ID 1 is offline

Comment: By the way, increasing partitions will not move existing data, just in case you weren't aware

Comment: Oh, I did not mention it, but an error occurred in broker01 that launched shell. However, the error (NotLeaderForPartitionException) occurred for 'target-topic-example-1' and is an acceptable error.

Comment: I wonder why UnknownServerException occurred on other topics not related to target-topic-example-1.

Comment: You're not modifying other topics at the moment, so there's no reason for those to throw any errors? Basically, unknown server is just a reclassified UnknownHostException - there's no network route that resolves to the advertised address of that broker

Comment: Previously, I have used the partition increment shell often, but this is the first time it has occurred. I used the shell today, but the error did not occur.
I think I should take a look at Kafka source. Thanks, cricket!

Comment: Your broker might have just been offline, or non responsive before... Hard to say. It might help to look at setting up some monitoring solution like JMX gathering

Answer (score 0):

Just altering the number of partitions isn't enough, you need to re-balance the cluster. The newer partitions are only active when the consumers are informed about these new partitions.

Please refer to my answer for process of adding partitions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58293572/8702415

I would also recommend to conduct preferred replica election. `./bin/kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh --zookeeper localhost:9092`