# Is it possible to consume kafka messages using key and partition?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-partition

I am using **kafka_2.12** version **2.3.0** where I am publishing data into kafka topic using partition and key. I need to find a way using which I can consume a particular message from topic using key and partition combination. That way I won't have to consume all the messages and iterate for the correct one.

Right now I am only able to do this

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props)
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topic"))
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100)
def data = records.findAll {
    it -> it.key().equals(key)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to consume topic/partitions is:

1. KafkaConsumer.assign() : [Document link](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign-java.util.Collection-)
2. KafkaConsumer.subscribe() : [Document link](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe-java.util.Collection-)

So, You can't get messages by key.

If you don't have a plan to expand partitions, consider using assign() method. Because all the messages that come with the specific key will go to the same partition.

How to use:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
TopicPartition partition = new TopicPartition("some-topic", 0);
consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition));

while(true){
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
    String data = records.findAll {
        it -> it.key().equals(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to look for a particular partition in a topic?

Comment: @AbhishekGharai Yes, Assign() method could manually assign a list of partitions to this consumer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "get messages by key from Kafka".

One solution, if practical, would be to have as many partitions as keys and always route messages for a key to the same partition.

**Message Key as Partition**

```
kafkaConsumer.assign(topicPartitions);
    kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(topicPartitions);

    // Pull records from kafka, keep polling until we get nothing back
    final List<ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>> allRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records;
    do {
        // Grab records from kafka
        records = kafkaConsumer.poll(2000L);
        logger.info("Found {} records in kafka", records.count());

        // Add to our array list
        records.forEach(allRecords::add);

    }
    while (!records.isEmpty());
```

**Access messages of a Topic using Topic Name only**

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(<Topic Name>,<Topic Name>));
     while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
             System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
     }
```

Comment: Is it possible to look for a particular partition in a topic?

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer&method=seekToBeginning